# matrix product of the two tensors

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, linear-algebra, tensor

How would you calculate matrix product of the two tensors in PyTorch?

```
x =  torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]).view(-1, 2)
y =  torch.Tensor([[2, 1]]).view(2, -1)
```

I am confused between these options.

[image]

Comment: `PyTorch`, not `TensorFlow` as in tag you applied

Comment: @graseza that's a question from _Udacity Scholarship_ . Please do your own research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the options from the code below:

```
In [188]: torch.einsum("ij, jk -> ik", x, y)
Out[188]: 
tensor([[4.],
        [7.],
        [7.]])

In [189]: x.mm(y)
Out[189]: 
tensor([[4.],
        [7.],
        [7.]])

In [193]: x @ y
Out[193]: 
tensor([[4.],
        [7.],
        [7.]])

In [194]: torch.matmul(x, y)
Out[194]: 
tensor([[4.],
        [7.],
        [7.]])
```

As you can see, all these approaches would yield us the same result.

---

`x*y` is a hadamard product (element-wise multiplication) and will not work in this case. Also, `torch.dot()` would fail as well because it expects 1D tensors. `torch.sum(x*y)` would just give a single scalar value and that is also wrong since you wish to do matrix multiplication, not an inner product.